# JS as a Single JavaScript File in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using RequireJS, but our project has gotten quite large.

```
requirejs([
    'util/utils',
    'util/image_store',
    'models/user_model',
    'util/analytics'
    ],function() { /* do start here */ });
```

I've taken that initial group and I've concatenated together of those files so now I want to do this:
    requirejs([
        'initial_download.js'
        ],function() { /* do start here */ });

Now how do I let the other files know, that say use models/user_model that they don't need to download it themselves that requires already did a define?

Like this in a hypothetical UserView.js:

```
define(['models/user_model'],function(UserModel) {
   function UserView() { /* */ }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you concatenated the files, you needed to wrap each file's contents into a named `define` call. This way when it loads, the modules resurrect themselves as if they were loaded from individual files:

```
;(function() {

    define('util/utils',function(){
        return utilsObject
    })

    define('util/image_store',function(){
        return imageStoreObject
    })

    define('models/user_model',function(){
        return userModelObject
    })

    define('util/analytics',function(){
        return analyticsObject
    })

    // you need this to make this an AMD module.
    // it does not matter what it returns, as your
    // main payload is above.
    define(function(){})

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the Require.js optimizer to do this for you: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html